# How can i add 2 buttons in rowDefinitions in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, row

I want to create a wpf application that has three rows and the top row contains text, buttons and Icons

Comment: Can you show your existing XAML to make your question clearer?

Comment: You should give a more specific definition of what your issue is and what you're trying to achieve. It's just guesswork at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution, but it depends on how you want the controls to be displayed.

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Text"/>
            <Button Content="Button"/>
            <!-- Add more controls -->
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```